# Show 3 random colors at once every 4 seconds with jQuery

Tags: jquery, random, setinterval

I have this code and I'm trying to show 3 random colors from an array, *at once*, every 4 seconds, but instead I get 1 color every 4 seconds, even if they are properly randomized...

What am I missing?

```
//set colors
var colors = ["white", "red", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "brown", "black", "violet", "purple", "pink", "green"];

//pick 3 of them randomly
var three_random_colors = (n) => {
    return colors.reduce((memo, val, index) => {
        var p = (n-memo.length); // How many remaining to choose.
        var q = colors.length-index; // How many remaining to choose from.
        if (Math.random() < p/q){
            memo.push(val);
        }
        return memo;
    }, []);
};

//output the colors on the HTML
var counter = 0; //start counter
var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");//the place where we change things
setInterval(change, 4000);//every 4 seconds run the following stuff:
function change() {
 var text = three_random_colors(3);//get what's inside "three_random_colors"
 elem.innerHTML = text[counter];//on div, add content <--- (I want 3 at once here! but I get only 1)
    counter++;
    if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; var text = three_random_colors(3); }//reset
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your `change` function only outputs one colour at a time. You can simplify it to just output (for example)

```
text.join(' ')
```

and you will see all three colours:

```js
//set colors
var colors = ["white", "red", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "brown", "black", "violet", "purple", "pink", "green"];

//pick 3 of them randomly
var three_random_colors = (n) => {
  return colors.reduce((memo, val, index) => {
    var p = (n - memo.length); // How many remaining to choose.
    var q = colors.length - index; // How many remaining to choose from.
    if (Math.random() < p / q) {
      memo.push(val);
    }
    return memo;
  }, []);
};

//output the colors on the HTML
var elem = document.getElementById("changeText"); //the place where we change things
setInterval(change, 4000); //every 4 seconds run the following stuff:
function change() {
  var text = three_random_colors(3); //get what's inside "three_random_colors"
  elem.innerHTML = text.join(' '); //on div, add content <--- (I want 3 at once here! but I get only 1)
}
```

```html
<div id="changeText"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty simply with [randojs.com](https://randojs.com), and this code will execute immediately for the first run- then every four seconds thereafter, and it will never repeat the same color more than once within the same three-color set. All I do is make a shuffled color array using [randojs](https://randojs.com)'s `randoSequence` function, [slice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) the first three values from that array, [map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) them to their raw values with `.value` (because randojs actually returns an array of *objects* in case you need to access the value's original index with `.index`), [join](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) those values together into a string, and stick them into `#color`'s innerHTML.

```js
function showRandomColors() {
  var colors = ["white", "red", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "brown", "black", "violet", "purple", "pink", "green"];
  document.querySelector("#colors").innerHTML = randoSequence(colors).slice(0, 3).map(i => i.value).join(" ");
}

showRandomColors();
setInterval(showRandomColors, 4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
<div id="colors"></div>
```

Like I said, this code uses [randojs.com](https://randojs.com), so if you want to use this code, make sure you have this in the head tag of your html document:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```